# How to write a program that inputs a word and count how many times the word appearing in given strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Input word

1.Does not contain any spaces.

2.Less than 15 characters.

Keep this things

1.Case sensitive

2.DO NOT use ‘string.h’.

3.Only the ‘stdio.h’ is allowed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int search(const char* str1, const char* str2)
int main(void)
{
    char input[15];
    char string1[400] = " Pinot noir is a red wine grape variety of the species Vitisvinifera. The name may also refer to wines created predominantly from Pinot noir grapes. The name is derived from the French words for pine and black. The word pine alludes to the grape variety having tightly clustered, pine cone-shaped bunches of fruit.[1].";
    char string2[400] = " Metallica is an American heavy metal band. The band was formed in 1981 in Los Angeles by vocalist/guitarist James Hetfield and drummer Lars Ulrich, and has been based in San Francisco for most of its career.[1][2] The band's fast tempos, instrumentals and aggressive musicianship made them one of the founding big four bands of thrash metal, alongside Megadeth, Anthrax and Slayer.";

    printf("string1: %s\n\n", string1);
    printf("string2: %s\n\n", string2);
    printf("Enter a word to count:");
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("'%s' is found %d times in the string1.\n", input, search(input, string1));
    printf("'%s' is found %d times in the string2.\n", input, search(input, string2));
    return 0;
}

int mystrlen(const char* str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        *(str++);
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int search(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    int result = 0;
    int len = mystrlen(str1);

    while (*str2 != '\0') {
        if (*str2 == *str1) {
            while (*str1 != '\0') {
                if (*(s1++) != *(s2++))
                    result = result * 1;
            }
            if (*(str2--) != ' ' || *str2 + len != ' ')
                result = result * 1;
            else if (*str2 + len == '.' || *str2 + len == ',')
                result++;
            result++;
        }
        *(str2++);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

string1: " Pinot noir is a red wine grape variety of the species Vitisvinifera. The name may also refer to wines created predominantly from Pinot noir grapes. The name is derived from the French words for pine and black. The word pine alludes to the grape variety having tightly clustered, pine cone-shaped bunches of fruit.[1].";

string2:" Metallica is an American heavy metal band. The band was formed in 1981 in Los Angeles by vocalist/guitarist James Hetfield and drummer Lars Ulrich, and has been based in San Francisco for most of its career.[1][2] The band's fast tempos, instrumentals and aggressive musicianship made them one of the founding big four bands of thrash metal, alongside Megadeth, Anthrax and Slayer.";

Enter a word to count: is

'is' is found 2 times in string 1.

'is' is found 1 times in string 2.

Comment: what is your question ? What is the problem in your code ?

Comment: 1) Make it compile 2) without warnings 3) Make it run 4) without errors. Start at 1

Comment: This makes no sense as a statement:  `*(str++);`  Just write `str++;`.  There's no reason to load the value it points to, only to discard it.

Comment: This can't possibly be what you want:  `*str2 + len`.  Did you mean `*(str2 + len)`, i.e. `str2[len]`?  What you have is just adding `len` to the character pointed to by `str2`.

Comment: You might want to take a step back and try to learn the basics of arrays, pointers, and strings before trying to tackle this.  There are many problems with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your `search` function and I thought your function didn't cover some cases like if word is immediately followed by question mark or semicolon. I have included some of those cases too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Find length of a char string
int mystrlen(const char* str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        str++;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
// Find count of str1 in str2
int search(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    int cnt = 0, 
        i = 0,
        j = 0,
        len = mystrlen(str1);

    for (i = 0; str2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str1[j] == str2[i]) {
            // if last char of str1 then check next char in str2
            // is followed by either space or . or ? or ! or , or ; or :
            // If yes, then a match is found
            if (j == len - 1 
                && str2[i + 1] != '\0' 
                && (str2[i + 1] == ' ' 
                    || str2[i + 1] == '.' 
                    || str2[i + 1] == '?' 
                    || str2[i + 1] == '!'
                    || str2[i + 1] == ','
                    || str2[i + 1] == ';'
                    || str2[i + 1] == ':'))
                cnt++;
            // if not last char of str2, increment j to check for next char
            else j++;

        }
        // if not matched with current char of str2, reset j
        else j = 0;
    }
    return cnt;
}
int main(void) {
    int cnt = search("island", "That is my island, isn't it?");
    printf("island appeared %d times\n", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the link where I tested it: https://ideone.com/BPbQwh